# Unable to bind views for .. $RecyclerViewHolders at ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView); in RecyclerViewHolders

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, butterknife

I am getting below error log:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to bind views for .. $RecyclerViewHolders
>   at butterknife.ButterKnife.bind(ButterKnife.java:322)
>                                                                               at butterknife.ButterKnife.bind(ButterKnife.java:279)
>   ...
>    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5482)
>                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4707)
>                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4617)
>                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1994)
>                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1390)

```
public class RecyclerViewHolders extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Context mContext;


    @Bind(R.id.tvRowServiceCenterName)
    CustomTextView tvRowServiceCenterName;
    @Bind(R.id.tvRowServiceCenterKmsValue)
    CustomTextView tvRowServiceCenterKmsValue;

    @Bind(R.id.ivRowServiceCenterImage)
    CircleImageView ivRowServiceCenterImage;
    @Bind(R.id.ivRowServiceCenterStatus)
    CircleImageView ivRowServiceCenterStatus;

    public RecyclerViewHolders(Context context, View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView); // Getting error here at runtime
        this.mContext = context;
        //itemView.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
}
```

I am also referring [Butterknife is unable to bind inside my Adapter Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31447998/butterknife-is-unable-to-bind-inside-my-adapter-class)

Also see [ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=ButterKnife.bind(this%2C+itemView)%3B) related issue.

But it can't helps me.  Am I missing something, or doing something wrongly?

Comment: Can you post the adapter code and item xml code ?

Have a look at this github issue comment https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/423#issuecomment-167086168

Comment: @RenaudBoulard .  Thanks for link. As per link I tried my code with `try.. catch` but it can't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below code:

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
@Bind(R.id.tvRowServiceCenterName)
CustomTextView tvRowServiceCenterName;
@Bind(R.id.tvRowServiceCenterKmsValue)
CustomTextView tvRowServiceCenterKmsValue;
@Bind(R.id.ivRowServiceCenterImage)
CircleImageView ivRowServiceCenterImage;
@Bind(R.id.ivRowServiceCenterStatus)
CircleImageView ivRowServiceCenterStatus;

private ViewHolder(View view, int viewType, Context context){
        super(view);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    }
}
```